# Vue l18n $t undefined

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I can use `$t` in components:

```
:label="$t('sign-up.terms-label')"
```

and in javascript:

```
 case 'email':
   this.errors.push(this.$t('sign-up.email-exists')); break;
```

But I cannot use it in extend:

```
import { extend, localize, ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate';
localize({
  cs: {
   names: {
     email: $t('sign-up.email-label'),
```

EsLint says that the function is undefined.

I want to localize the field names for vee-validate as described here:

https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-the-default-i18n

I18N is defined this way:

```
Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'cs',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'cs',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
});
```

Comment: Would you be more specific? I have read that document many times but I do not understand where the problem is.

Comment: In the section I linked, $t doesn't come out of nowhere but from `i18n.$t`.

Comment: I have added more code how I initialize the i18n library. Complete source code: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/spa/src/i18n.js. The docs shows how a local variable is defined. But this is not my case.

Comment: The guide I posted is very close. It likely doesn't show how it's done if it's in another module because imports are common JS knowledge that isn't specific to this library. I've tried to explain it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There's an error because `$t` isn't defined in this scope.

As [the guide](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-other-i18n-libraries) shows, `$t` should be referred as a method on `vue-i18n` instance outside Vue components.

If it's defined in another module, it should be imported from a module where `vue-i18n` instance was exported from:

```
import i18n from './i18n';

...

localize({
  cs: {
   names: {
     email: i18n.$t('sign-up.email-label'),
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call extend from the [created()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) method, at which point you will have access to `this.$t`.

```
created() {
  localize({
    cs: {
     names: {
       email: this.$t('sign-up.email-label'),
  //...
}
```